# See code of imported FMU/FMI block in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, fmi

I'm trying to debug a FMU file which is a part of a larger simulation, and my problem is that I have no direct access to the code inside. I've tried importing the FMU file to Simulink, but what I get is a blackbox block with I/Os. My goal is to directly access the governing C/C++ code going on inside the block, is there any way to do this, preferably with Simulink/MATLAB?

Is what I'm describing next to impossible as a FMU file is already compiled?

Comment: Neither MATLAB or Simulink will magically allow you to see into the file.  If you have access to the C++ code then you'll be able to view it, if you don't then using MATLAB or Simulink is not going to help.

Answer (score 0):

An FMI/FMU can be exported either with the binaries or source code in it. Maybe the FMU you are using, only contains binaries but no sources directory in it? And also some companies want to protect their IP by only providing the binaries and not the source codes. So I think it is one of those FMUs. And to answer your question, you cannot see FMU source code in matlab. Matlab will only show you the box with the Inputs and outputs and when you run it, through the FMU interface, it runs the binary.